# resultat BETWEEN is null

Tags: mysql, date, jpql

this is my jpql

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Subscribe.countByDate", query = "SELECT COUNT (s.idSubscribe) FROM Subscribe s WHERE s.dateInscription BETWEEN :dateS AND :dateF"),
```

this is my facade :

```
    public Number subSexeDate(String v, Date dated, Date datef) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Subscribe.countByDate");
    //query.setParameter("sexe", v);
    query.setParameter("dateS", dated, TemporalType.DATE);
    query.setParameter("dateF", datef, TemporalType.DATE);
    return (Number) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

this is my controller

```
 public List<Number> subSexeDate() {
    sexe();
    Date d1= new Date(2008-01-07);
    Date d2= new Date(2010-01-01);
    List<Number> nb = new ArrayList<Number>();
    for (String var : sexe()) {

        nb.add(ejbFacade.subSexeDate("homme", d1, d2));
    }
    return nb;
}
```

the result is: [0, 0]

the real problem

`Date d1 = new Date(2007-01-01); long x = d1.getTime(); long y = System.currentTimeMillis(); Date d2 = new Date(); d2.setTime(y); d1.setTime(x); List<Number> nb = new ArrayList<Number>(); for (String var : sexe()) { nb.add(ejbFacade.subSexeDate(var, d1, d2)); System.out.println(d1.toString()+"date2"+d2);}`

but résult of system.out : Infos: Thu Jan 01 01:00:02 CET 1970date2Sun May 26 11:55:31 CEST 2013 –

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the issue has to do with the way you are constructing your `Date` objects.
You are writing this:

```
Date d1= new Date(2008-01-07);
```

Which is the same as this:

```
long x = 2008 - 1 - 7;
Date d1 = new Date(x); // or new Date(2000L);
```

Which I suspect is not what you wanted. Use a `DateFormat` and parse your date string instead.